# Semantics of <expan>, <ex> and <am> tags in TEI

Tags: abbreviation, tei

For abbreviations, the TEI documentation §11.3.1.2 recommends using either `<abbr>` with `<am>` or `<expan>` with `<ex>`. But what happens with a case like the German clipping bzw. (= beziehungsweise). Letters "b", "z" and "w" belong both to the abbreviation and the expansion, but the period belongs only to the abbreviation. I would write it as

```
<expan>b<ex>e</ex>z<ex>iehungs</ex>w<ex>eise</ex><am>.</am></expand>
```

so that "b", "z" and "w" are outside the `<ex>` and `<am>` tags and the period is inside the `<am>` tag.

Is that correct?

It is not what TEI recommends (in no example do I see an `<am>` inside an `<expan>`) but I see no other way to have the three cases:

1. characters only in abbreviation (which I put inside `<am>`),
2. characters only in expansion (which I put inside `<ex>`), and
3. characters both in abbreviation **and** in expansion (which I put outside both `<ex>`and `<am>`).